# How to prove this statement through induction?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I need to show that for the terms of the fibonnaci sequence, where $n \ge 1$, $a_{n-1}^2 + a_{n}^2 = a_{2n-1}$

So far, I have this:

$a_{n-1}^2 + a_{n}^2$

$=a_{n-1}^2 +(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$

$=a_{n-1}^2 +a_{n-1}^2 + a_{n-2}^2 + 2a_{n-1}a_{n-2}$

$=a_{n-1}^2 + a_{2n-3} + 2a_{n-1}a_{n-2}$

$=a_{n-1} (a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2}) + a_{2n-3}$

$=a_{n-1} (a_{n} + a_{n-2}) + a_{2n-3}$

I'm kind of stuck at this point. How can I simplify the first part so it becomes $a_{2n-2}$? I was thinking that would be necessary so I could have $a_{2n-3} + a_{2n-2} = a_{2n-1}$

Comment: Begin at the beginning.  What is the base case.  What is the inductive hypothesis, and what are you gong to show us?

Comment: Is $a_0 = a_1 = 1$? Because then for $n = 1$, $a_{n-1}^2 + a_n^2 = a_0^2 + a_1^2 = 2$ but $a_{2n-1} = a_1 = 1$ so the base case is already false.

In fact for $n = 1$, $a_{n-1}^2 + a_n^2 = a_0^2 + a_1^2$ while $a_{2n - 1} = a_1$ and since $a_0, a_1 > 0$, these two values are never equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_{n-1}^2+a_{n}^2=a_{2n-1}$

base case: $n = 2$

$a_1^2 + a_2^2 = a_3\\
1^2 + 1^2 = 2$

Suppose for all $n\le k, a_{n-1}^2+a_{n}^2=a_{2n-1}$

We must show that

$a_{k}^2+a_{k+1}^2=a_{2k+1}$

$a_{2k+1} =$$ a_{2k} + a_{2k-1}\\
  = 2a_{2k-1} + a_{2k-2}\\
  = 3a_{2k-1} - a_{2k-3}$

$a_{2k+1} = 3(a_k^2 + a_{k-1}^2) - (a_{k-1}^2 + a_{k-2}^2)$

by the inductive hypothesis

$3a_k^2 + 2 a_{k-1}^2 - a_{k-2}^2\\
3a_k^2 +  a_{k-1}^2 + (a_{k-1}+a_{k-2})(a_{k-1}-a_{k-2})\\
3a_k^2 +  a_{k-1}^2 + (a_{k})(a_{k-1}-a_{k-2})\\
a_k(3a_k + a_{k-1}-a_{k-2}) +  a_{k-1}^2\\
a_k(2a_k + 2a_{k-1}) +  a_{k-1}^2\\
2a_k^2 + 2a_ka_{k-1} +  a_{k-1}^2\\
a_k^2 + (a_{k}+a_{k-1})^2\\
a_k^2 + a_{k+1}^2$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you completely understand what a proof by induction entails.
Lets start from the beginning. Every proof by induction starts with a base case. In this case, lets suppose $a_{0} = 0$ and $a_{1} = 1$. Then we have $a_{0}^2 + a_{1}^2 = 0^2+1^2 = 1 = a_{2(1)-1}$. Hence our base case is true.

Now we do the induction step. In induction, we assume our $n^{th}$ case is true, and using that, we try and show the $(n+1)^{th}$ case is also true. If we can do that, then all cases that follow the base case must be true. Here, this means we *assume* $a_{n-1}^2 + a_{n}^2 = a_{2n-1}$, and we *want to show* $a_{n}^2 + a_{n+1}^2 = a_{2(n+1)-1}$

So lets try and show that $a_{n}^2 + a_{n+1}^2 = a_{2(n+1)-1}$ is true.

Subtracting the induction assumption, we get $a_{n+1}^2 - a_{n-1}^2 = a_{2n+1}-a_{2n-1} = a_{2n}$. Note that we can do this because we are *assuming* that our induction hypothesis is true. See if you can take it from here and argue that these two sides are equal.